# Selenium can't click div button inside google pay iframe

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

Currently working on google pay integration test automation and got stuck with element location problem.
Google payment flow opens in separate window which I managed by finding proper handle in session

```
driver.switchTo().window(googlePayWindowHandle);
```

after after i got transferred to the page where i need to click on the "Continue" buttone and there are few tricks with it:

- it's in the iframe which i managed by moving to the proper frame

```
WebElement iframe = checkPresenceOfElementWithWait(driver, By.name("sM432dIframe"), WAIT_DURATION);
WebDriver frameDriver = driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

- button i need to click is a div with role="buttone".
  As per other articles i've tried locating button element with wait for it to be clickable

```
WebDriverWait frameWait = new WebDriverWait(frameDriver, WAIT_DURATION);
WebElement element = frameWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@role='button']")));
```

But it always fail with error

```
TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //div[@role='buttone']
```

also i tried another approaches like using **waitForElementPresence** and it seems that selenium cannot locate the element inside the iframe. To make sure that button is within the frame i entered chrome console and searched by xPath and it worked.

P.S.:
also tried javascript executor and still no luck.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: check the typo here: `//div[@role='buttone']`

Answer (score 0):

```
ele="//div[text()='Pay']";
```

js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);

i pass the element as javascript executor click , it worked but not with ordinary click method